# Using react-testing-library with storyshots?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, react-testing-library

Is it possible to use react-testing-library with the storybook storyshots addon? I'd like to generate some tests for react components which do not use enzyme.

Comment: this article may help you => https://medium.com/@mtiller/testing-react-components-using-storybook-and-cypress-1689a27f55aa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably a bit late for you, but just been looking at this exact problem. This is the config I came up with which seems to work for me.

```
import initStoryshots from "@storybook/addon-storyshots";
import path from "path";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";


const reactTestingLibrarySerializer = {
  print: (val, serialize, indent) => serialize(val.container.firstChild),
  test: (val) => val && val.hasOwnProperty("container")
};

initStoryshots({
  configPath: path.join(__dirname, "..", "config", "storybook"),
  framework: "react",
  integrityOptions: { cwd: path.join(__dirname, "stories") },
  renderer: render,
  snapshotSerializers: [reactTestingLibrarySerializer],
  storyKindRegex: /^((?!.*?DontTest).)*$/
});
```

The secret is to pass in a custom Jest [serializer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#snapshotserializers-array-string) for the [snapshotSerializers](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/addons/storyshots/storyshots-core#snapshotserializers) option that gets the container from the result of the render function and passes its firstChild to be serialized.

If you need to, you can modify the content of the container before serializing, to remove unstable attributes or entire elements using the DOM api.

Comment: Must add that it is in my limited experience much faster and much more robust than Enzyme alternative in this context.