# Storyshots with react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snapshot, storybook, react-testing-library

I'm trying to add snapshots using `storybook` `v5.0.5` and `react-testing-library` `v6.0.3`  to do structural testing of all my stories.

I'm trying to follow the docs:

https://github.com/infinitered/addon-storyshots/blob/master/README.md#serializer

But instead of enzyme, using `react-testing-library`.

With Enzyme:

```js
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';
import toJSON from 'enzyme-to-json';

initStoryshots({
  renderer: mount,
  serializer: toJSON,
  framework: 'react',
  storyRegex: /.*\.stories\.js/,
});
```

With `react-testing-library` (What I'm trying to do):

```js
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots'
import { render } from 'react-testing-library'

initStoryshots({
  renderer: render,
  framework: 'react',
  storyRegex: /.*\.stories\.js/,
})
```

I'm not sure, that the `render` method is the **renderer** that the Storyshot api requires. And also needs a **serializer** but I don't found an equivalent in `react-testing-library`.

With these configuration, is creating the snapshots. However, these snapshots are not correct at all...

Looks that the nodes doesn't have properties, and instead, is displaying a lot of useless properties...

Example of created snapshot:

```
exports[`Storyshots Components.Accordion with a custom button 1`] = `
Object {
  "asFragment": [Function],
  "baseElement": <body>
    <div />
    <div>
    </div>
  </body>,
  "container": <div>
  </div>,
  "debug": [Function],
  "findAllByAltText": [Function],
  "findAllByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "findAllByLabelText": [Function],
  "findAllByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "findAllByRole": [Function],
  "findAllByTestId": [Function],
  "findAllByText": [Function],
  "findAllByTitle": [Function],
  "findByAltText": [Function],
  "findByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "findByLabelText": [Function],
  "findByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "findByRole": [Function],
  "findByTestId": [Function],
  "findByText": [Function],
  "findByTitle": [Function],
  "getAllByAltText": [Function],
  "getAllByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "getAllByLabelText": [Function],
  "getAllByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "getAllByRole": [Function],
  "getAllBySelectText": [Function],
  "getAllByTestId": [Function],
  "getAllByText": [Function],
  "getAllByTitle": [Function],
  "getAllByValue": [Function],
  "getByAltText": [Function],
  "getByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "getByLabelText": [Function],
  "getByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "getByRole": [Function],
  "getBySelectText": [Function],
  "getByTestId": [Function],
  "getByText": [Function],
  "getByTitle": [Function],
  "getByValue": [Function],
  "queryAllByAltText": [Function],
  "queryAllByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "queryAllByLabelText": [Function],
  "queryAllByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "queryAllByRole": [Function],
  "queryAllBySelectText": [Function],
  "queryAllByTestId": [Function],
  "queryAllByText": [Function],
  "queryAllByTitle": [Function],
  "queryAllByValue": [Function],
  "queryByAltText": [Function],
  "queryByDisplayValue": [Function],
  "queryByLabelText": [Function],
  "queryByPlaceholderText": [Function],
  "queryByRole": [Function],
  "queryBySelectText": [Function],
  "queryByTestId": [Function],
  "queryByText": [Function],
  "queryByTitle": [Function],
  "queryByValue": [Function],
  "rerender": [Function],
  "unmount": [Function],
}
`;
```

Can anybody help me with this? If I don't provide the `renderer` on the config, the snapshot is empty... However, looks that something is missing in this renderer...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I needed every storyshoot in a separate file and after reading this: [Using react-testing-library with storyshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029273/using-react-testing-library-with-storyshots), I came up with this config that works for me.

- it didn't render not needed `testing-library` params
- it is in separate files

Maybe someone will find it usefull.

```js
import path from 'path';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import initStoryshots, { multiSnapshotWithOptions, Stories2SnapsConverter } from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

const reactTestingLibrarySerializer = {
  print: (val, serialize) => serialize(val.container.firstChild),
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
  test: (val) => val && val.hasOwnProperty('container')
};

initStoryshots({
  framework: 'react',
  integrityOptions: { cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'stories') },
  test: multiSnapshotWithOptions({
    renderer: render
  }),
  snapshotSerializers: [reactTestingLibrarySerializer],
  stories2snapsConverter: new Stories2SnapsConverter({
    snapshotsDirName: './__snapshots__/',
    storiesExtensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
  }),
  storyKindRegex: /^((?!.*?DontTest).)*$/
});
```